# Mysql issue with IN and ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, sql-in

I am experiencing a strange issue with a query against the following Mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `BulkTransuploads` (
  `bulktransuploads_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id of the upload',
  `bulktransuploads_time` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'The upload time',
  `bulktransuploads_val_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'TransactionID value. value 1',
  `bulktransuploads_val_orderid` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'OrderID value. value 2',
  `bulktransuploads_val_url` varchar(400) NOT NULL COMMENT 'URL value. value 3',
  `bulktransuploads_val_tracking` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tracking value. value 4',
  `bulktransuploads_status_v1` varchar(150) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Status for value1. OK or error message',
  `bulktransuploads_status_v2` varchar(150) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Status for value2. OK or error message',
  `bulktransuploads_status_v3` varchar(150) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Status for value3. OK or error message',
  `bulktransuploads_status_v4` varchar(150) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Status for value4. OK or error message',
  PRIMARY KEY (`bulktransuploads_id`)
) ENGINE=ARCHIVE AUTO_INCREMENT=242 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I need to extract some values having the ids, so I thought the shortest way is to use IN clause.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM BulkTransuploads WHERE bulktransuploads_id IN (233,231,232)\G;
```

The above query return the following result:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
          bulktransuploads_id: 231
*************************** 2. row ***************************
          bulktransuploads_id: 232
*************************** 3. row ***************************
          bulktransuploads_id: 233
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have deleted other columns values to spare some space here. All in all this query does almost what I expected, though I expected a different order (233,231,232) as this order was written in the query (IN clause). As I need to have the results ordered descending I modified my query as follow:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM BulkTransuploads WHERE bulktransuploads_id IN (233,231,232) ORDER BY bulktransuploads_id DESC\G;
```

My new query returns an awkward result:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
          bulktransuploads_id: 200
*************************** 2. row ***************************
          bulktransuploads_id: 200
*************************** 3. row ***************************
          bulktransuploads_id: 200
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I cannot understand why it returns 3 times id 200. The ONLY difference between queries is `ORDER BY bulktransuploads_id DESC` , therefore undoubtedly ORDER BY clause is messing my results, but my question is Why?

Comment: Can you share some data ?

Comment: can you create a sqlfiddle?

Comment: sqlfiddle is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0da17/4  I have inserted some random data. Data itself is irrelevant, what does count here is the ids

Answer (score 0):

> You need to change the ENGINE that you're using, instead use InnoDB.

Modify the CREATE TABLE query as:

```
CREATE TABLE `BulkTransuploads` (
  `bulktransuploads_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id of the upload',
  `bulktransuploads_time` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'The upload time',
  `bulktransuploads_val_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'TransactionID value. value 1',
  `bulktransuploads_val_orderid` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'OrderID value. value 2',
  `bulktransuploads_val_url` varchar(400) NOT NULL COMMENT 'URL value. value 3',
  `bulktransuploads_val_tracking` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tracking value. value 4',
  `bulktransuploads_status_v1` varchar(150) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Status for value1. OK or error message',
  `bulktransuploads_status_v2` varchar(150) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Status for value2. OK or error message',
  `bulktransuploads_status_v3` varchar(150) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Status for value3. OK or error message',
  `bulktransuploads_status_v4` varchar(150) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Status for value4. OK or error message',
  PRIMARY KEY (`bulktransuploads_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=200 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Your suggestion works, however I used ARCHIVE storage engine to restrict further UPDATE or  DELETE queries. Your approach implies me to create triggers. With triggers in Mysql is another issue, they do not support ROLLBACKs, instead I have to write some queries that can simulate an error and only in this way the trigger will fail, thus DELETE or UPDATE will also fail. But what is the reason my query acts strange on ARCHIVE storage engine?